# Variable is not seen by json_encode in script section php (laravel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables

Could you help with with following  "i" is variable from for loop which is not seen by json_encode 
I receive following error code :
Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i'

I tried $i but it's also not working, but if I put for example 1 on the place of "i", it's working fine (return value of 1 element)

Could you please help me to find proper syntax that will help to solve my problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cs='USD';           
    var numberoftours = {!! json_encode($cart->totalQty) !!};
    var price=0;

    for (i=1; i<= numberoftours; i++){
       price={!! json_encode($cart->items[i]['tourprice']) !!};
       $('#tourfinal'+i).html(cs+' '+ price);   
    };
});
```